# Задать путь поиска классов через опцию -Xbootclasspath

Tags: java, docker

Для подгрузки внешней либы хочу использовать Xbootclasspath.

В Dokerfile это написал вот так, но при выполнении - создании образа, получаю ошибку.
Быть может у меня неправильный синтаксис?

```
RUN set -x \
    && $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: App.jar \
```

Error: Could not find or load main class App.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App.jar

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб запускать `*.jar` нужна опция `-jar`. В таком виде, как у вас сейчас параметр `App.jar` интерпретируется как имя класса.

Нужно так:

```
RUN set -x \
    && $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a: -jar App.jar
```